# Please tell me which one is correct and why

Tags: word-usage

1. "I like living in this house. But it's a pity that garden is small"
2. "I like living in this house but it's a pity that **the** garden is small"

Comment: You've got things the wrong way around! It's the "complementizer" ***that*** (as used in #2) that's optional in this context, not the definite article ***the***. Note that it's not really possible for ***that*** to be a "pronoun/ article" *(**that** garden, **this** garden, **a** garden)* in #1, because that would conflict with earlier ***this** house* - you *must* have some kind of article there, and the obvious choice is ***the*** (whether or not you precede it by ***that*** as an optional complementizer).

Answer (score 2):

1 either omits an article before "garden", or it uses "that" as a specifier for "garden".

You can't omit a specifier before "garden", and "that" is unlikely to be used, so 2 is the better choice. You would use "that garden" to distinguish a garden from other gardens, but most houses will have only one garden, and the word "the" suffices to point to it in the context of a house.

In other words, answer 1 is not impossible, but it's unlikely.